# ruby win32api question related to export and return values

Tags: ruby, winapi

I am  trying out the win32api of ruby. I am facing two issues:-

1. I understand the basic concept, trying to work it with Ruby. I get segmentation fault sometimes. Is it because the parameter type(that I specify in the new) does not match actual the function definition? It certainly corresponds to that observation, but I am not sure. Wanted confirmation from someone.
2. The API I am trying is from wlanapi.dll(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706759%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . I need to automate wifi connections from my windows machine for testing. As you can see, the function has both _out parameters and a return value. I wanted to know which of these corresponds to the "export" of the win32api new function definition(http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/lib_windows.html) . I thought it is the actual return value i.e. success or one of the error messages. In that case, how do I get the other _out params like the handle, I need to use this handle for the other functions.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post your call, I would only be guessing, but yes it is possible that the segmentation fault would come from an invalid `Win32API.new` call.  That defines the structure of the call.

I am not familiar with that function, but just looking at the definition on MSDN, I believe the following would be a valid call to it (assuming a 32-bit platform with 4 byte pointers). The first two parameters here are defined as 32-bit unsigned integers with the 'L'. The second one is actually treated as a pointer by the API but is supposed to be NULL, so passing a zero should be okay for that.  The last two parameters are pointers.  The 'I' indicates an integer return value.

The `negver = [0].pack('L')` creates a 4 byte "string" that acts as the pointer that receives the 4 byte negotiated version value.  In the actual call, I am not completely sure about the very first parameter; you may need to adjust that for your environment.

```
api = Win32API.new( 'wlanapi', 'WlanOpenHandle', ['L', 'L', 'P', 'P'], 'I')
negver = [0].pack('L')
handle = [0].pack('l')  # this assumes 4 byte pointer
ret = api.call( 2, 0, negver, handle )
puts "WlanOpenHandled returned #{ret}"
puts "Negotiated version: #{negver.unpack('L')}, Handle is #{handle.unpack('L')}"
```